# How to write a List<List<string>> to an Excel (.xls or .xlsx) file?

Tags: c#, excel, export, xls, xlsx

I'd like to write some data to an Excel file (.xls or .xlsx) using C#.

Here's my code at the moment :

```
int length = readData.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;

List<List<string>> dataList = new List<List<string>>();

foreach (string line in readData.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    List<string> partsLine = new List<string>();
    partsLine.AddRange(line.Split('\t'));
    dataList.Add(partsLine);
}
```

So, I'm splitting all the data in lines.

Then I split each line with '\t' separator, and add each part of the line in a list.

And at the end I have a list containing all the lists of split lines.

So the list looks like :

- List1 {txt1, txt 2} = first line
- List2 {txt3, txt 4, txt 5, txt 6} = second line
- List3 {txt7, txt 8, txt 9, txt 10} = third line
- List4 {txt 11, txt 12} etc.

All of the lists don't have the same lenght as you can see.

What I'd like to do is writing all the lists to a CSV file.

Each list would fill a row and a certain number of columns, depending of the lenght of the list (i.e. txt1 should be (row1, col1), txt2 should be (row1, col2), txt3 should be (row2, col1), txt4 would be (row2, col2)...).

I've already managed to export data in a .csv file, but when I'm trying to do it with an .xls (or .xlsx), the data doesn't format correctly.

Here's the code for .csv writing :

```
        const string separator = ";";

        // Writing the list to the .csv file
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path + "\\data.csv", false))
            {
                dataList.ForEach(line =>
                {
                    var lineArray = line.Select(c => c.Contains(separator) ? c.Replace(separator.ToString(), "\\" + separator) : c).ToArray();
                    writer.WriteLine(string.Join(separator, lineArray));
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            textBoxData.AppendText("Error while writing data to .csv file (" + ex.Message + ")");
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I really don't know if I understood you problem. But are you aware that a XLS/XLSX file have a particular internal structure? That's obvious is not a simple delimited file?

Comment: Hi. Don't know exactly what your problem is, and what you're trying to achieve. But then again, it seems that all your code, besides the streamwriter, is just the following `writer.Write(.Replace(";", "\\;").Replace("\t", ";")` If so, this will output a valid CSV (But Semicolon) file. I've tried with the following string "a\tb\tc\r\nd\te", and excel managed to open the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to an excel file using an OLEDB connection and write to it like you would a SQL connection. If there's no reason you need a CSV, just do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to write my `List<list<string>>` in a xls file, here's my code :

```
    private void CreateXLS(string data)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\data.xls";

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        // List of lists containing each line split by part
        List<List<string>> dataList = new List<List<string>>();

        List<string> valuesA = new List<string>();

        // Building the list
        foreach (string line in data.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            List<string> partsLine = new List<string>();
            partsLine.AddRange(line.Split('\t'));
            dataList.Add(partsLine);
        }

        int row = 1;
        int col = 1;

        foreach (List<string> list in dataList)
        {
            foreach (string str in list)
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[row, col] = str;

                if (list.IndexOf(str) == list.Count - 1)
                    col = 1;
                else
                    col++;
            }
            row++;
        }


        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(path, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);

        textBoxData.AppendText("\nData saved to .xls file (path : " + path + ")");
    }
```